# JSDoc for jQuery Deferred.done callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-deferred, jsdoc

I want to create adequate documentation and enable hinting for functions that return Deferred objects. What is the proper way (if there is one) to document Deferred.done callback with JSDoc? So far I have:

```
/**
 * Creates component element.
 * @param {Object} settings
 * @returns {Deferred}
 */
$.fn.customDialogue.createElement = function (settings) {
    var deferred = $.fn.dialogue.createElement(settings);
    $.when(…).done(function (dialogueElement) {
        deferred.resolve(dialogueElement.customDialogue(settings));
    });
    return deferred;
};
```

I want to indicate in the documentation that the returned Deferred's `done()` callback accepts `@param {jQuery} element`, e.g.:

```
$deferred.done(function(element){
    …
});
```

### Edit:

I'm using PhpStorm, it doesn't fully support JSDoc, but the following seems to work. Post a better solution if you know one.

```
/**                                                                                              
 * @function                                                                                     
 * @name Deferred.done                                                                           
 * @param {function(element:jQuery)} callback                                                    
 */                                                                                              

/**                                                                                              
 * Creates new component element and returns a deferred object.                                  
 * @param {Object} settings                                                                      
 * @returns {Deferred}                                                                           
 */                                                                                              
$.fn.customDialogue.createElement = function (settings) {
    var deferred = $.fn.dialogue.createElement(settings);
    $.when(…).done(function (dialogueElement) {
        deferred.resolve(dialogueElement.customDialogue(settings));
    });
    return deferred;
};
```

Looks like this: http://d.pr/i/j506

Comment: `deferred.done(function() { deferred.resolve(…) })` does not make any sense. A promise can be resolved only once.

Comment: Eagle eye! There's another promise involved that resolves the main deferred. Updated the code, thanks for pointing out @Bergi.